# Will the GTK+ timeout callbacks be called in strict time order?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, gtk, gtk#

When I add many different timeouts (with each `intervall==0`) in a thread, which is **not** the main thread (where `gtk_main()` resides)...

```
g_timeout_add(0, func, NULL);
```

... will then the different `func()` callbacks occur in the **same order** I called the corresponding `g_timeout_add()`'s?

The reason I'm asking is because GTK# is using internally timeouts to implement [`Application.Invoke()`](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=M%3aGtk.Application.Invoke%28System.EventHandler%29) (see [Application.cs](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/master/gtk/Application.cs#L211) and [Timeout.cs](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/master/glib/Timeout.cs#L89)).

**EDIT:** The concerning glib files are

- http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gmain.c
- http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/ghook.c

Answer (score 4):

Internally, g_timeout_add calls [g_hook_insert_sorted](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#7hampNszsxQ/pub/softwares/analyse4pc.tgz|_NI-g-Hx9Dg/Analyse4pc/scr/glib.c/GHOOK.C&q=g_hook_insert_sorted%20lang:c++). If g_timeout_add_full is used, the priority determines the ordering, otherwise the hook is added at the end of the list. Hooks are executed in order, so when only g_timeout_add is used, the answer is yes.

Unfortunately, there is not no explicit guarantee, and to me, it looks like an implementation detail which might change in the future.

Comment: OK. But I cannot really find a call to `g_hook_insert_sorted()` inside *gmain.c* (I added a link in the question)?

Answer (score 1):

How about enforcing the order of the calls by storing your callbacks explicitly in a list, then using a single g_timeout_add() to call a function that iterates over that list?

```
static gboolean
call_in_order (GList* callbacks)
{
  for (; callbacks != NULL; callbacks = callbacks->next)
    {
      g_assert (callbacks->data != NULL);
      GSourceFunc callback = (GSourceFunc)(callbacks->data);

      callback(NULL);
    }
}


...

 GList *callbacks = NULL;
 callbacks = g_list_append(callbacks, func1);
 callbacks = g_list_append(callbacks, func2);
 callbacks = g_list_append(callbacks, func3);
 callbacks = g_list_append(callbacks, func4);

 g_timeout_add(0, (GSourceFunc)call_in_order, callbacks);
```